# PowerShell group object Cumulative / Running total

Tags: arrays, powershell, group-by, foreach, sum

My data looks like below

```
 Name   Numbers
 Bob    1
 Bob    1
 Bob    0
 Tom    1
 Tom    0
Steve   0
Steve   1
```

Would like the end result to look like this:

```
Name    Numbers Total numbers
Bob     1        1
Bob     1        2
Bob     0        2
Tom     1        1
Tom     0        1
Steve   0        0
Steve   1        1
```

I have tried group Object -

```
Import-Csv 'C:\New folder\test.txt' | Group-Object Pitcher |
Select-Object Name, Numbers, @{ n='Total numbers'; e={ ($_.Group.Numbers) } }
```

And also this:

```
$csvfile='C:\New folder\test.txt'
$csvlength = (Get-Content "C:\New folder\test.txt").length
[int]$Sum = 0`
$csv=Import-csv -Path $csvfile -ea 0 | Sort-Object Name
for($i=0; $i -lt $csvlength; $i++) {``foreach($row in $csv){ 
    if($previous){
        if($previous.Name -eq $row.Name){
            $Sum += $row.Numbers
        }
    }
    $previous = $row
}
```

Comment: Is it a csv (comma separated values), or a txt file with no means of value distinction?

Comment: It is a csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a Csv you can use a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) to keep track of each Total Count for each value in `Name` then construct a new object using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3):

```
$map = @{}
Import-Csv $csvPath | ForEach-Object {
    $map[$_.Name] += $_.Numbers -as [int]
    $_ | Select-Object *, @{N='Total numbers'; E={ $map[$_.Name] }}
}
```

Output should look like this using the example data:

```
Name  Numbers Total numbers
----  ------- -------------
Bob   1                   1
Bob   1                   2
Bob   0                   2
Tom   1                   1
Tom   0                   1
Steve 0                   0
Steve 1                   1
```